# Call to a member function relationLoaded() on string on voyage admin

Tags: laravel, voyager

I installed the voyager admin successfully from [here](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager)

On my client page, I created a custom registration which is derived from auth. I can register the user successfully.

After I installed the voyager admin, I added a new user on client's registration form. Then, when i tried to access the `http://localhost:8000/admin` and then error occurred as seen on the image.

[image]

Below is the image of the line 53:

[image]

And below is the entire code of VoyagerUse.php

```
<?php

namespace TCG\Voyager\Traits;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\Role;

/**
 * @property  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection  roles
 */
trait VoyagerUser
{
public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Voyager::modelClass('Role'));
}

/**
 * Check if User has a Role(s) associated.
 *
 * @param string|array $name The role to check.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasRole($name)
{
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('role')) {
        $this->load('role');
    }

    return in_array($this->role->name, (is_array($name) ? $name : [$name]));
}

public function setRole($name)
{
    $role = Voyager::model('Role')->where('name', '=', $name)->first();

    if ($role) {
        $this->role()->associate($role);
        $this->save();
    }

    return $this;
}

public function hasPermission($name)
{
    if (!$this->relationLoaded('role')) {
        $this->load('role');
    }

    if (!$this->role->relationLoaded('permissions')) {
        $this->role->load('permissions');
    }

    return in_array($name, $this->role->permissions->pluck('key')->toArray());
}

public function hasPermissionOrFail($name)
{
    if (!$this->hasPermission($name)) {
        throw new UnauthorizedHttpException(null);
    }

    return true;
}

public function hasPermissionOrAbort($name, $statusCode = 403)
{
    if (!$this->hasPermission($name)) {
        return abort($statusCode);
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: What exist in line 53 of VoyagerUser.php ?

Comment: hello. just edited my question

Comment: I think you have a role attribute in the user table aren't you ?

Comment: yeah you're right. what's next? I need that role field under user table

Comment: You should simply change the name of this attribute because Voyager add a relation named role as well !!

Comment: oh. wow., thank you maraboc.,  I deleted it and it worked. I just rename it and change my code. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the VoyagerUser in line 53 :

```
if(!$this->role->relationLoaded('permissions')){ ...
```

The role here is considered as a relation not a field :)

and the error

> Call to a member function relationLoaded() on string

means that you have the role as attribute in the User Model

So all you have to do is rename the role attribute to something else and everything will work perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should simply change the name of your attribute named role because Voyager add a relation named role as well

Comment: You can write down the solution if it is that simple so that others can see this too. Otherwise, write a comment. PLease read the rules.