# Laravel , Voyager - Call to a member function relationLoaded() on string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, voyager

I'v installed Voyager tool for Laravel , after creating a new User and try to  login , I saw this

[image]

That is what I get , I've checked the role_id in the User table in the database its recorded as Null . I've to enter the role_id manually even if I changed the role from user to admin in the dashboard its not changed in the database

thats from where the error comes

[image]

So what is the problem and how can I solve it ?

Comment: I recommend you posting an issue on the [Voyager repository](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager).

Comment: There are various [similar issues](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/872) reported regarding `relationLoaded()`.

Comment: @Camilo Thank you . I found the solution .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call to a member function relationLoaded() on string on voyage admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491081/call-to-a-member-function-relationloaded-on-string-on-voyage-admin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a `role` column in your User model, to solve the problem change the column name for example to `user_role` and test again.

**Why ?**

Because Voyager expect that you have a relation named `role` not a column.

Comment: The same nothing change .  But thank you I've found the solution there 
https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/2119

Comment: I have answered the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46492358/4881811) withe the same screenshots, what's going on here ??

Comment: I don't know . I saw your answer for the same question and did it but it doesn't work .
But the solution I put , is working .